# access none static fields in android

Tags: android, static-methods, android-dialogfragment

Hi i have defined a dialog that when it gets dismissed i want to notify the activity and do some logic.

The issue i am having is that the logic i have to do is none static and so i cant find a way to execute this function.

the function in question is changing the visibility of a view.

code is below

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout

private static View.OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
     dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        if(noSelected()){
                            setVisibility(GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
 }
}
```

any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: At which line getting issue?

Comment: setVisibility line

Comment: Could you also update the code block to be a little more valid. Your variable doesn't have a name ...

Answer (score 0):

The `View.OnClickListener` variable is static and therefore your implementation isn't an anonymous inner class having a reference to the `CustomView` object. Remove the static modifier and you'll be able to access `setVisibility()`.